# Need to paste picture into Powerpoint then defining its location without selecting it

Tags: excel, vba, location, powerpoint, paste

Here is a small snippet of my code where I paste a chart from Excel into Powerpoint as an enhanced metafile and then move it to a predefined location:

```
PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNumber).Shapes.PasteSpecial (ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)

PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = ChartTop
PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = ChartLeft
```

The problem occurs when the user clicks the mouse between the first and second line of the code. Because the shape is no longer selected the vba code above fails.

Ordinarily this wouldn't be a problem but the macro as a whole runs for a long time with this happening many times in a loop. Is there a feasible solution to defining the pasted picture's location without the need to select the shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nearly never need to select anything to work with it.

```
' if you're running the code from within PowerPoint:
Dim oSh as Shape
' or if from Excel:
Dim oSh as Object

' Get a reference to the newly pasted shape
' Don't miss the (1) at the end
Set oSh = PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNumber).Shapes.PasteSpecial (ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)(1)

With oSh
  .Top = ChartTop
  .Left = ChartLeft
End With
```